# Workers Dataproc stops unexpectedly

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

We're launching a replication instance to replicate data from Mysql to BigQuery. After some hours, the instance is in `Killed` state.

When watching the logs, we have that (I added the 3 comments):

```
// DATA IS CORRECTLY LOADED IN BIGQUERY
2022-08-30 03:25:14,799 - INFO  [bq-daemon-2125:i.c.d.b.BigQueryEventConsumer@705] - Loading batch 1661829830877 of 933 events into staging table for [db.table]
2022-08-30 03:26:44,800 - INFO  [bq-daemon-2127:i.c.d.b.BigQueryEventConsumer@705] - Loading batch 1661829974724 of 1 events into staging table for [db.table]
2022-08-30 03:26:44,803 - INFO  [bq-daemon-2126:i.c.d.b.BigQueryEventConsumer@705] - Loading batch 1661829922476 of 914 events into staging table for [db.table]

// ERROR IS FROM HERE
2022-08-30 03:27:10,766 - INFO  [TwillContainerService:i.c.c.i.a.r.d.AbstractProgramTwillRunnable@281] - Program run program_run:[name].-SNAPSHOT.worker.DeltaWorker.[runid] completed. Releasing resources.
2022-08-30 03:27:10,768 - DEBUG [TwillContainerService:i.c.c.l.a.LogAppenderInitializer@137] - Stopping log appender TMSLogAppender
2022-08-30 03:27:42,635 - DEBUG [main:i.c.c.l.a.LogAppenderInitializer@137] - Stopping log appender TMSLogAppender
2022-08-30 03:27:46,410 - DEBUG [provisioning-task-2:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@125] - Executing DEPROVISION subtask REQUESTING_DELETE for program run program_run:default.[name].-SNAPSHOT.worker.DeltaWorker.[runid].
2022-08-30 03:27:47,263 - DEBUG [provisioning-task-2:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@129] - Completed DEPROVISION subtask REQUESTING_DELETE for program run program_run:default.[name].-SNAPSHOT.worker.DeltaWorker.[runid].
2022-08-30 03:28:17,819 - DEBUG [provisioning-task-2:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@125] - Executing DEPROVISION subtask POLLING_DELETE for program run program_run:default.[name].-SNAPSHOT.worker.DeltaWorker.[runid].
2022-08-30 03:28:18,471 - DEBUG [provisioning-task-2:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@129] - Completed DEPROVISION subtask POLLING_DELETE for program run program_run:default.[name].-SNAPSHOT.worker.DeltaWorker.[runid].
2022-08-30 03:28:21,230 - DEBUG [provisioning-task-2:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@116] - Completed DEPROVISION task for program run program_run:default.[name].-SNAPSHOT.worker.DeltaWorker.[runid].

// THAT'S THE END OF THE LOGS, NOTHING ELSE
```

As you can see, data are correctly loaded in batchs in BigQuery, then suddenly, with no error message, the instance is deprovisioned.

It started about 3 weeks ago and since then, we constantly have to restart manually the worker.

Comment: What log is this? What does "replication instance" mean in this context?

Comment: It's the log from the Data Fusion job that i downloaded. "Replication instance" means a replication job that we launched in Data Fusion and that we configured with a MySQL source and a BigQuery target so our data from our database are replicated in BigQuery. And this replication job is running inside a Data Fusion instance.

Comment: I see, I am not familiar with Data Fusion, not sure if it creates a Dataproc cluster or not in this case.

Comment: @bjovanov This problem may occur  if the schema gets changed after you enable the CDC, as DDL changes are not supported when CDC is enabled. If you have a support plan, I would recommend you to raise a ticket with [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub). Or you can also create a thread in  Google’s [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: It looks like something is telling the worker to stop. There may be useful information in the app-fabric logs (available from the System Admin page). If you search for the runid, it may give some clue about what triggered the stop.